# angular 6 routing to home page

Tags: angular, routes

I'm stuck with with a the following problem and need someone's help in resolving it.

the requirement is I have to root back to home page after clicking back arrow in browser or back button in mobile devices from whatever the component or page I'm in, I have tried with multiple scenarios and different codes which didn't worked. I'm always getting redirected to the last page I have visited in back cycle manner. I have tried adding routing, adding confirm form with if else logic, nothing worked.

Can someone please help me on this? I'm using angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click event on the back button and just change the route to home:

```
<button (click)="backtoHome()"><-</button>
```

Now in the component:

```
constructor(private route: Router){}

backtoHome(){
   this.route.navigate(['/']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on  browser back button,  add a home icon , so whenever u click on icon u can route to homepage.

this.router.navigate(['/home']) // here 'home' is the path please specify ur homepage route path.